# Generate BINGO cards by EXCEL but with missing numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

I have an old bingo game. The game has a drawing machine with balls that is missing some balls with numbers.
I want to create an excel sheet to generate cards for BINGO that will skip the missing numbers, and the cards themselves will not have duplicate numbers when generated.

Table with numbers to generate Bingo Cards:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | B | 1 | I | 16 | N | 31 | G | 46 | O | 61 |
| **2** | B | 2 | I | 17 | N | 32 | G | 47 | O | 62 |
| **3** | B | 3 | I | 18 | N | 33 | G | 48 | O | 63 |
| **4** | B | 4 | I | 19 | N | 34 | G | 50 | O | 64 |
| **5** | B | 6 | I | 20 | N | 35 | G | 51 | O | 66 |
| **6** | B | 7 | I | 21 | N | 36 | G | 52 | O | 67 |
| **7** | B | 8 | I | 22 | N | 37 | G | 53 | O | 68 |
| **8** | B | 9 | I | 23 | N | 39 | G | 54 | O | 69 |
| **9** | B | 10 | I | 24 | N | 41 | G | 55 | O | 71 |
| **10** | B | 11 | I | 25 | N | 42 | G | 56 | O | 72 |
| **11** | B | 12 | I | 26 | N | 44 | G | 57 | O | 73 |
| **12** | B | 13 | I | 27 | N | 45 | G | 58 | O | 74 |
| **13** | B | 14 | I | 28 |  |  |  | 59 | O | 75 |
| **14** | B | 15 | I | 29 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **15** |  |  |  | 30 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I use to find random numbers from array:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$14;INT((RAND()*(13)+1)))
```

Bingo Cards:

[image]

Comment: you would need to provide more details, is the first screenshot the input data?, then what is the meaning of letters: B,I,N,G,O? What is the purpose of the random number generated? how this relates to the first screenshot?, what is the purpose of the second screenshot? is the expected output?, please work more on your question and if there is any input data, put it in [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) format, so we can reproduce it in Excel.

Comment: =TAKE(SORTBY(B1:B14,RANDARRAY(COUNT(B1:B14),1)),5,1) to take 5 random from column B

Comment: David Leal, do you know nothint about BINGO?

Answer (score 4):

### Generate Bingo Cards (Missing Balls)

```
=LET(table,B1:F16,br,5,
    GenCol,LAMBDA(col,r,
        TAKE(SORTBY(col,RANDARRAY(SEQUENCE(ROWS(col)))),r)),
    d,DROP(table,1),
    VSTACK(TAKE(table,1),
        DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(d)),LAMBDA(rr,c,
            HSTACK(rr,GenCol(TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(d,c),2),br)))),,1)))
```

- If you prefer empty cells instead of `#N/A` errors, replace the `2` with `1`.
- The conditional formatting for the missing values is `=IFNA(B2)` or `=B2=""` respectively (after selecting `B2:F16`).

[image]

Comment: you could also replace the TOCOL argument to 3 to leave out blanks and/or errors.

Answer (score 3):

If you rearrange your data like in the example below, this would work:

`=TAKE(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(,5),LAMBDA(a,b,LET(c,TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(A2:E16,b),1),HSTACK(a,SORTBY(c,RANDARRAY(ROWS(c),,1,ROWS(c),1)))))),5,-5)`

[image]

Otherwise
`=TAKE(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(,5,2,2),LAMBDA(a,b,LET(c,TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(A1:J15,b),1),HSTACK(a,SORTBY(c,RANDARRAY(ROWS(c),,1,ROWS(c),1)))))),5,-5)`

[image]

Comment: I ended up with the same thing with some redundant complications since it's a small dataset. Hopefully, you know that I came up with it on my own. Either way, if you wish I can delete my post.

Comment: That's alright. Yours is different from mine and I guess we both liked the challenge.
My main advise would be to buy a new Bingo-set, but then we wouldn't have this nice challenge ;)

Comment: HaHa, yep it is a correct answer. I need new one bingo game ;)